# Are there any differences between magnetic fields produced by different "materials"?

Tags: magnetic-fields, vector-fields

are there any differences between magnetic fields produced by different "materials" ?
No matter the answer on the above question, when magnetic fields interact with each other or other fields, is there any "anomaly" observed? 
 
Lets call this: "Third and Final Piece".
Good luck and bye bye.

Answer (score 2):

if you put a magnet in a cardboard box and measured everything you could about the field outside the box, there would be no clue as to what the magnet itself was made out of. So the field of the magnet carries with it no imprint of the material it is made of.

Comment: not only the magnet cannot be "reconstructed" from knowing its external field but one cannot even say if the external field was created by a permanent magnet or by a solenoid

Comment: You can to a degree. If you put a magnet in a cardboard box and ask if it is an iron magnet inside, the answer is "maybe". If you ask if it is glass, the answer is "no". But I don't really think this is what the OP is asking.